# JPanel Checkbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I wonder how i can hide the second drawOval when i check the checkbox:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g); 
            g.drawOval(175, 185, 80, 45); 
            g.drawOval(170, 185, 80, 45);
```

I'm a beginner in Java and i can't find on how to hide this.

So to be more specific

I have a checkbox in the design panel
and when i click the checkbox
the second drawOval should disappear.

And can this work with like 6 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And can this work with like 6 lines?

No, you'll have to modify that code. Wrap the drawOval line that you want to draw or not draw based on the check box state in an if block. Inside the if boolean test -- check to see if the JCheckBox is checked, and if so, draw the oval. If not don't draw it -- simple!

```
if (myCheckBox.isSelected()) {
   g.drawOval(....)
}
```

Also add an ActionListener to the JCheckBox that does one thing: calls `repaint()` on the JPanel.

Comment: @Ditger: I'm not clear what you're asking, but in general, if you want code to run only when a certain condition is true, you use an if block or its if-else and else variants, to control program flow. Keep at it.

Comment: i fixed it on my own :D